# How send variable in OnClickListener

Tags: android

I will make anonym function onClick for new widget. I load variable data from res/raw. But i need some ID for load it. I use `getResources().getIdentifier()`
It looks like this:

```
TextView ans = new TextView(this);
String exm = "demo";
 ans.setOnClickListener(
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, Video.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("ex", getResources().getIdentifier( exm,"raw", getPackageName()));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
            );
```

I have error about variable non inner class variable. But i can't `final` it - it will be variable. How can i send my variable in new Object `OnClickListener` and function `onClick` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have it as a class variable

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        String exm = "demo";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ans.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(FullscreenActivity.this, Video.class);
                            intent.putExtra("ex", getResources().getIdentifier( exm,"raw",  getPackageName()));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make it a member variable of your containing `Activity`.